# ActionListener doesn't work from other class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Here I have test application, where I can't understand why `ActionListener` from `Test class` doesn't work. Each help will make me happy. Thanks :)
Here's code;

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
Main(){
    GUI m = new GUI();
    this.getContentPane().add(m.panel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setBounds(0,0,400,200);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main();
            new Test();
        }
    });
}
}

class GUI{
GUI(){
    initComp();
    btn();
}
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button1;
JTextField textField;
private void initComp(){
    textField = new JTextField(10);
    button1 = new JButton("TEST");
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button1);
}
public String getEnteredText(){
    return textField.getText().trim(); //trim dodatkowy
}

public void btn(){
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Test from GUI-class");
        }
    });
    }
  }

class Test{
Test(){
    buttonGetter();

}
GUI m = new GUI();
String kol;
public void buttonGetter(){
    m.button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Test from Test-class");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test` doesn't add anything to any components/windows, so it's never visible on the screen, only the instance of `GUI`, which is created in `Main` is visible.

A possibly better solution would be to use class inheritance to extend the `GUI` and override the `btn` method in order to provide your custom implementation, which might look something like...

```
public class Test extends GUI {

    @Override
    public void btn() {
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Test from Test-class");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then instead of creating an instance of `GUI` in the `Main` method, you create an instance of `Test` instead, for example;

```
GUI m = new Test();
```

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    Main() {
        GUI m = new Test();
        this.getContentPane().add(m.panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    public class GUI {

        GUI() {
            initComp();
            btn();
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1;
        JTextField textField;

        private void initComp() {
            textField = new JTextField(10);
            button1 = new JButton("TEST");
            panel.add(textField);
            panel.add(button1);
        }

        public String getEnteredText() {
            return textField.getText().trim(); //trim dodatkowy
        }

        public void btn() {
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Test from GUI-class");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class Test extends GUI {

        @Override
        public void btn() {
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Test from Test-class");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```